# How to increase or decrease value to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables - bags and market.
[image]

At this time, in the bags table has data like :
[image]

If I add data from the market table, the qty column in the table bag will decrease according to the amount inputted in the market table. And the total price column will calculate the total_qty (market) * price (bags)

Comment: Seems like you want to store values calculated from other columns? That's generally a bad idea, too much risk of data inconsistency. Consider _views_ or _computed columns_ instead. (Or manage using triggers.)

Comment: really? can you give me any solution how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation is not as clear as you think it is.  By the way, the answer to your question is that you need a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

From My Understanding I suggest for this concept to use Trigger,

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER trg_insert
 AFTER INSERT ON market

 begin
 update bags set qty = ((select qty from bags where id=1)-(select 
 market.total_qty from market where 
 id=1) ))
 ,price = ((select price from basgs where id=1)-(select market.total_prc 
  from market where 
 market.id=1)))
 where bags.id = 1;
  END$$
 DELIMITER $$
```

> Now i am using with static values which you are provided,
>   Try this code.

Comment: it's error sir.. 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin
update bags set qty = (bags.qty-(select market.total_qty from market whe' at line 4'